# Why the default darktheme property for both MaterialApp and CupertinoApp are light themes?

Tags: flutter

What is the rationale for this decision?

The [manual](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/darkTheme.html) sounds slightly insane:

> The `ThemeData` to use when a 'dark mode' is requested by the system.

> [...] Defaults to the value of `ThemeData.light()`

Wait. What?

Is there any case where someone would NOT want it default to `ThemeData.dark()`? Is this for historical reasons? Is there any gotcha I am missing?